# Index out of range trying to add to slice

Tags: arrays, loops, go

```
var bar string
var i int
var a []string
for foo, _ := reader.NextWord(); foo != bar; foo, _ = reader.NextWord() {
    bar = foo
    fmt.Print(foo)
    a[i] = foo
    i++
}
```

Shouldn't this be creating a nil slice and then adding the value to the appropriate place? I keep getting index out of range so I assume it's not adding to `a[i]`...

Checking length first with

```
if len(a) > 0 {
    a[i] = foo
}
```

seems to help, but not getting the results I expected. I'll keep playing around.

Update: I did end up using append... I meant to update this thread but thank you both.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/steven-ferrer/gonsole"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("test.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    reader := gonsole.NewReader(file)

    // cycle through
    var bar string
    var i int

    var quality []string = make([]string, 0)
    var tempName []string = make([]string, 0)
    var name []string = make([]string, 0)

    for foo, _ := reader.NextWord(); foo != bar; foo, _ = reader.NextWord() {
        bar = foo

        if strings.Contains(foo, "(normal)") {
            quality = append(quality, "normal")
            for state := 0; state < 1; foo, _ = reader.NextWord() {
                if foo == "|" {
                    state = 1
                }
                tempName = append(tempName, foo)
            }
            nameString := strings.Join(tempName, "")
            name = append(name, nameString)
        } else if strings.Contains(foo, "(unique)") {
            quality = append(quality, "unique")
            for state := 0; state < 1; foo, _ = reader.NextWord() {
                if foo == "|" {
                    state = 1
                }
                tempName = append(tempName, foo)
            }
            nameString := strings.Join(tempName, "")
            name = append(name, nameString)
        } else if strings.Contains(foo, "(set)") {
            quality = append(quality, "set")
            for state := 0; state < 1; foo, _ = reader.NextWord() {
                if foo == "|" {
                    state = 1
                }
                tempName = append(tempName, foo)
            }
            nameString := strings.Join(tempName, "")
            name = append(name, nameString)
        }
        if tempName != nil {
            tempName = nil // clear tempName
        }
        i++
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slice `a` needs to be allocated utilizing `make`.

```
var a []string = make([]string, n)
```

where `n` is the size of the slice.

Comment: Ah thank you. I thought slices could resize on their own, unlike arrays and that was the point. So if n were 3, could I only have a[0], a[1], a[2]?

Comment: Yes, you could utilize the builtin package's [append](https://golang.org/src/builtin/builtin.go?h=append#L134) function to resize the slice dynamically.

Comment: That's why one normally uses `append`, e.g. `a = append(a, foo)`, which which case you don't need to use `make`.

Answer (score 1):

Removing some of the context-specific parts of your code, you should be using the `append` method against a dynamic-length slice.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    book := "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    var words []string

    for _, word := range strings.Split(book, " ") {
        words = append(words, word)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", words)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/LMejsrmIGb9

If you know the number of values up front, the same can be achieved for a fixed length slice by using `words := make([]string, 5)`, but I doubt this is what you want in this case.

The reason your code is causing you errors is because your slice isn't initialized at any given length, so your indexes don't yet exist. Generally when working with a slice, `append` is the method you want.

Opposite to this, when working with existing slices (ie, `range`ing an slice), the reason you're able to set the values using indexes is because the index has already been allocated.

Comment: What did Ralph Waldo Emerson say about consistency? What do the Go Code Review Comments say about Declaring Empty Slices? https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#declaring-empty-slices

Comment: That is accurate, I will update my comment to reflect the point. Although, the preference to utilize the same initialization method when defining multiple variables is also a reality, hence why I used that here.